# In javascript, is an empty string always false as a boolean?

Tags: javascript, string, boolean

in javascript,

```
var a = '';
var b = (a) ? true : false;
```

`var b` will be set to `false`.

is this a defined behavior that can be relied upon?

Comment: Are you sure, I am getting `false` here: http://jsfiddle.net/8CKbd/

Comment: I took it a step further. String with spaces is true. if (' ') {console.log('!')} but the ' ' == 0 is true.

Comment: I think that @JonH edition is wrong, the empty string `''` is evaluated to false in a boolean context so if `a = '';` then `a ? false : true` => `'' ? false : true` => `false ? false : true` => `true` ( because is the evaluation for a false value). I think it should be `var b = (a) ? true : false;` to be correct with the next statement.

Comment: @PhoneixS edited, hope it's more meaningful now.

Comment: @SwissCoder it wasn't that is not readable but that it outputs another answer. Now I have corrected it.

Comment: @PhoneixS perfect! sorry had gotten confused myself while editing :D

Answer (score 255, accepted):

Yes. Javascript is a dialect of ECMAScript, and ECMAScript language specification clearly defines this behavior:

> **ToBoolean**
>
> The result is false if the argument is the empty String (its length is zero);
> otherwise the result is true

Quote taken from http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Comment: Aaaaand it's settled

Comment: One caveat is that `new String("")` is truthy! This is because it is an object, whereas the short form `""` represents the primitive value version. The same goes for `new Number(0)` and even `new Boolean(false)`. It's a good reason not to use the object versions in your code, and it does mean that `if (str.length)` handles this edge case whereas `if (str)` would not.

Answer (score 67):

Yes. All `false`, `0`, empty strings `''` and `""`, `NaN`, `undefined`, and `null` are always evaluated as `false`; everything else is `true`.

And in your example, b is `false` after evaluation. (I think you mistakenly wrote `true`)

Comment: `null` is not `false`, neither `true`, `null` is `null`. https://jsfiddle.net/sq1Lkpg0/

Comment: @Bruno, You can perform the same test with `NaN` and `undefined`.  They are not `false` but they are falsy.  Which is what was asked.

Answer (score 17):

```js
var a = '';
var b = (a) ? false : true;   // fixed!
console.log(b);               // => true
```

> var `b` will be set to `true`.
>
> is this a defined behavior that can be relied upon?

As answered above, **yes**, that is the defined behavior of an empty string **in a conditional** (an `if` expression, `||`, `&&`, `? :`, ...). (The [standard says](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.12) that the internal **ToBoolean** operation must be applied.)

The evaluation is different when the empty string is used **in a comparison** (see [Truth, Equality and JavaScript](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/)), even though the results are **mostly the same**:

```js
// conditional (note: evaluation to false prints false here!)
console.log('' ? true : false); // zero length     => false

// comparisons
console.log('' == true);        // +0 === 1        => false
console.log('' == false);       // +0 === +0       => true
console.log('' === true);       // different types => false
console.log('' === false);      // different types => false
```

Explanation: Essentially, when the operands of `==` have different types, JavaScript tries hard to convert them to Numbers, according to their **value**, ([using](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.9.1) [operations](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.9.3) the standard calls **ToNumber** and **ToPrimitive**), and then it internally applies `===`.  But when you use `===` directly, the types are not converted, so comparing a String to a Boolean is always `false`.

Roughly speaking, JavaScript **conditionals** (**ToBoolean**) test for a **defined, non-null, non-zero, non-empty, non-false value** (an empty String is ... empty, the Numbers -0 or +0 are ... zero, NaN is not a defined number, but an empty Object is apparently not really empty), or as I like to think, **conditionals** test for **a (true) thing**, while `==` compares the **apparent, carefully converted *values*** (**ToPrimitive**, **ToNumber**) of its operands, and `===` looks for **exact sameness**.

```
if (X) {}        // is X a (true) thing?
if (X == Y) {}   // are the values of X and Y same-ish?
if (X === Y) {}  // are X and Y exactly the same?
```

There are more examples in [Truth, Equality and JavaScript](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/) where this distinction really matters, e.g. `'0'` is `true` in a conditional (non-zero length, or, *it is a thing*), but `false` in a `==` comparison (the *value* is zero). `'1'` again, is `true` in both cases (it is a thing and has a non-zero value).

```js
console.log('' ? true : false);   // zero length     => false
console.log('' == true);          // +0 === 1        => false
console.log('0' ? true : false);  // non-zero length => true
console.log('0' == true);         // +0 === 1        => false
console.log('1' ? true : false);  // non-zero length => true
console.log('1' == true);         //  1 === 1        => true
```

Comment: At first I thought, "pssh, that's overkill, this was well-answered already." But that was well-presented and informative. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

`var b` will be set to `true`. This is because an empty string counts as a 'falsey' value in JavaScript as do some other values.

Please look at http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/ for falsy values

Comment: You are wrong in your answer. `var b` actually will be set to `true` because it's the opposite of `var a` if you look at the code.

Comment: @bombek Thanks - I'll upate. Looks like the original question was edited after my answer (the values were swapped around)

Comment: So many edits in the question, it's again the other way around.

Answer (score 5):

> Examples of expressions that can be converted to false are those that
>   evaluate to null, 0, the empty string (""), or undefined.
>   (see [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators))

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can rely on that behavior.

A shorter way to write it will be:

```
var b = !!a;
```