# Splitting string by whitespace, without empty elements?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to explode an string using javascript to pick searchterms, whitespace-separated. However I get empty array elements if a searchterm is ended by a whitespace, as shown below.

What should I do instead to avoid post-processing this array and removing empty elements?

```
var str = "searchterm1 searchterm2";
console.log(str.split(" ")); // ["searchterm1", "searchterm2"]

var strb = "searchterm1 "; // Note the ending whitespace
console.log(strb.split(" ")); // ["searchterm1", ""]
```

Comment: regarding this old question.  you just add `.filter(e => e)` on the end of the split, to eliminate empty items.  this is typical when you split on newlines.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You could simply match all non-space character sequences:

```
str.match(/[^ ]+/g)
```

Comment: If there could be tabs or new lines, you can match /\S+/g.

Comment: `"".match(/[^ ]+/g)` returns `null`, but my use case would need `[]`

Answer (score 65):

No matter what splitter this always works:

```
str.split(' ').filter(function(i){return i})
// With ES6
str.split(' ').filter(i => i)
```

Filter logic also can change in some other cases.

Comment: Do you know, **why** this works? Documentation says `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.  
In this case empty elements seem to be ignored by this method and therefore aren't in the resulting array.   
 I don't understand why this test isn't done for empty elements.

Comment: Answer is simple, if you have more than one space character, you'll have empty string ('') in your results, and because `if('')` is false, `filter` function filter strip them in the final result.

Comment: If you want your filter function to return a boolean value instead of a string (although this is surprisingly not a problem, even with Typescript), you can also do `str.split(' ').filter(Boolean)`

Answer (score 20):

This is a bit old, but for documentation purposes there is also another neat way.

```
someString.filter(Boolean);

// Example
['fds', '', 'aaaaa', 'AA', 'ffDs', "", 'd'].filter(Boolean);
// Output
["fds", "aaaaa", "AA", "ffDs", "d"]
```

**Edit**

> How does it work ?

The following are identical

```
.filter(Boolean)
.filter((value) => Boolean(value))
```

`Boolean()` as function behave as a converter of any type to Boolean by the standard input to output.

References:
[Global Objects -> Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean#description)
[Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)
[Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: It works because JavaScript consider an empty string (length is 0) as false. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692982/in-javascript-is-an-empty-string-always-false-as-a-boolean#:~:text=58-,Yes.,false%20%3B%20everything%20else%20is%20true%20.

Comment: I meant to ask: what does `Boolean` mean as argument?

Comment: Ok, First, we need to understand that these two are identical `.filter(Boolean)` is equal to `.filter((value) => Boolean(value))`. Now that is out of the way, `Boolean()` as function behave as a converter of any type to Boolean. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean#description In Addition to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: Thank you. IMO this needs to be part of the reply.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, you are right, I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest solution IMO. `trim()` first to get rid of leading/trailing whitespace, then split by whitespace.

```js
function split(str) {
  return str.trim().split(/\s+/);
}

console.log(split('foo bar baz'));
console.log(split('  foo  bar  baz '));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a function that you can use, just extend String:

```
 String.prototype.splitNoSpaces = function(){
     return this.split(' ').filter(function(i){return i});
 };

 //Now use it!
 var classString = "class1    class2 class3    class4";
 var classArray = classString.splitNoSpaces();

 //classArray[0] is class1
 //classArray[1] is class2
 //classArray[2] is class3
 //classArray[3] is class4
```

Thanks to @user1079877 for the hint

Answer (score 0):

Add function:

```
//Some browsers support trim so we check for that first
if(!String.prototype.trim) {  
  String.prototype.trim = function () {  
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');  
  };  
}
```

Then call trim on the string:

```
var strb = "searchterm1 "; // Note the ending whitespace
console.log(strb.trim().split(" ")); // ["searchterm1"]
```

Comment: What about multiple spaces in between like `"foo\x20\x20bar"`?

Comment: @Gumbo `str.trim().split(/ +/g)`