# split with regexr with no empty elements

Tags: javascript, split

I want output be like this: 
['YY','RR']
with no empty elements

```js
function pntSq(m){
    let a = m.split(/([A-Z][A-Z])/gi)
    console.log(a)
}
pntSq("YYRR")
//    output :
//    [ '', 'YY', '', 'RR', '' ]
```

Comment: add a filter [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2843625/3462319)

Comment: or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39184134/3462319)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead of using split.

```js
function pntSq(m){
  return m.match(/[A-Z]{2}/g);
}

console.log(pntSq('YYRR'));
```

Comment: But your answer assumes that contiguous letters would always occur in pairs, which may not be the case.

Comment: My answer assumes that the information in the question is correct otherwise I'd be here all day thinking up edge-cases that have nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Link: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XhCRq4/1)

This matches any 2 uppercase letters together, but note that they may be different.

```regex
[A-Z]{2}
```

To match the same uppercase letter 2 times. This ensures that it's the same letter repeated and not different letters.

```regex
([A-Z])\1
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript may not support splitting on lookbehinds.  One workaround would be to do this in two steps.  First we can replace on the following regex pattern:

```regex
([A-Z])(?!\1)(?=.)
```

This will capture any capital which in turn is followed by a *different* letter (and also not the end of the string).  Then, we replace with a single space.  As the second step, we simply split on space to get the output array we want.

```js
function pntSq(m) {
    m = m.replace(/([A-Z])(?!\1)(?=.)/g, "$1 ");
    console.log(m);
    var a = m.split(/ /g);
    console.log(a);
}

pntSq("YYRRAAABBBBBCC");
```