# Why is a method on an object being true?

Tags: javascript

Can you explain me what's the difference between `ModelState.IsValid` and `ModelState.IsValid()` in the example below? (Both of them are working)

```js
var func = function () {
  var ModelState = {
    IsValid: function () {
      return true
    }
  };
  
  // ModelState.Isvalid() is working, too
  document.body.innerHTML = ModelState.IsValid 
      ? 'ModelState is valid' : 'ModelState is invalid'
};
```

```html
<button onclick="func()">Click me</button>
```

As you can see above, `ModelState` is a json object. If I can call `ModelState.IsValid`, is `IsValid` called `json property` in this case?

Comment: ModelState is not a JSON object. Its an object literal. And IsValid is a property of the ModelState object literal.

Comment: @TarunDugar is correct. I think you are confused on the the difference between calling a function without parenthesis. Here is a similar question to help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246928/in-javascript-does-it-make-a-difference-if-i-call-a-function-with-parentheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IsValid` is a function. So when you do this `ModelState.IsValid`, this will return the function and not its value.

`ModelState.IsValid()` this will execute it and give you return value.

```js
var func = function () {
  var ModelState = {
    IsValid: function () {
      return true
    }
  };
  
  console.log("ModelState.IsValid: ", ModelState.IsValid)
  
  console.log("ModelState.IsValid():", ModelState.IsValid())
  
  // ModelState.Isvalid() is working, too
  document.body.innerHTML = ModelState.IsValid 
      ? 'ModelState is valid' : 'ModelState is invalid'
};
```

```html
<button onclick="func()">Click me</button>
```

Now, why ternary operator works:

JS tries to convert value to `Boolean`. If this is not possible, then availability is checked. So when you do

```
if("")
```

it will convert `""` to `0` and `0` is considered as false, but if it has value, it is considered as true.

```js
var a = "";

alert(a?true:false);

a = "function(){...}";

alert(a?true:false);
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried and seen the difference. But when I change `document.body.innerHTML = ModelState.IsValid ? 'ModelState is valid' : 'ModelState is invalid'` to `document.body.innerHTML = ModelState.IsValid() ? 'ModelState is valid' : 'ModelState is invalid'`. I'm getting same result.

Comment: Can you tell me more about that?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope that helps

Comment: it looks like `implicit conversion 'string' to 'boolean'`

Comment: Yes. You can refer [following post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692982/in-javascript-is-an-empty-string-always-false-as-a-boolean) for reference.

Comment: Many thanks! That's really help :)

Answer (score 1):

> If I can call ModelState.IsValid, is IsValid called json property in
>   this case?

`ModelState` is an object literal and `isValid` is a property of this object.

if you change your code to

```
document.body.innerHTML = ModelState.Isvalid 
      ? 'ModelState is valid' : 'ModelState is invalid'
```

it will output `ModelState is invalid`

Comment: you've changed nothing with the code

Comment: Why? `ModelState.IsValid` is a non-null method, which is truthy, so it seems this should print `modelState is valid`.

Comment: @torazaburo sorry, someone edited the code and for some reason that edit was accepted!!