# Trying to set a radio button in HTML document using javascript with data from cookie

Tags: javascript

I have a question.  I got this registration form that stores the values into a cookie based on an ID name.  When you go back to the same registration form and fill in the ID name that was already saved in a cookie, it will pull the data from cookie and prefill the form.

I have the following code and it works on form fields, but not on radio buttons.  Not sure what is going on with radio buttons

```html
//This function fills in the form based on entered conference ID
function fillForm(name) {
    var cookie = getCookie(name).toString();
    var newCookie = decodeURIComponent(cookie);
    var newArray = newCookie.split(";");

    //For testing values to make sure they're there
    alert(newArray);

    document.getElementById("title").value = newArray[0];
    document.getElementById("firstname").value = newArray[1];
    document.getElementById("lastname").value = newArray[2];
    document.getElementById("addressone").value = newArray[3];
    document.getElementById("addresstwo").value = newArray[4];
    document.getElementById("city").value = newArray[5];
    document.getElementById("state").value = newArray[6];
    document.getElementById("zipcode").value = newArray[7];
    document.getElementById("tel").value = newArray[8];
    document.getElementById("email").value = newArray[9];
    document.getElementById("website").value = newArray[10];
    document.getElementById("position").value = newArray[11];
    document.getElementById("companyname").value = newArray[12];

    if(newArray[13]) {
        document.getElementById("mealone").checked = true;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("mealtwo").checked = true;
    }

    if(newArray[15]) {
        document.getElementById("sesonea").checked = true;
    }
    else if(newArray[16]) {
        document.getElementById("sesoneb").checked = true;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("sesonec").checked = true;
    }

    if(newArray[18]) {
        document.getElementById("sestwoa").checked = true;
    }
    else if(newArray[19]) {
        document.getElementById("sestwob").checked = true;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("sestwoc").checked = true;
    }

    if(newArray[21]) {
        document.getElementById("sesthreea").checked = true;
    }
    else if(newArray[22]) {
        document.getElementById("sesthreeb").checked = true;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("sesthreec").checked = true;
    }

    document.getElementById("billfirstname").value = newArray[24];
    document.getElementById("billlastname").value = newArray[25];

    if(newArray[26]) {
        document.getElementById("carda").checked = true;
    }
    else if(newArray[27]) {
        document.getElementById("cardb").checked = true;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("cardc").checked = true;
    }

    document.getElementById("cardnumber").value = newArray[29];
    document.getElementById("csv").value = newArray[30];
    document.getElementById("cardexpmonth").value = newArray[31];
    document.getElementById("cardexpyear").value = newArray[32];
}
```

It's driving me nuts.  I setup an alert to make sure I can see all the data correctly in the array, but it's not selecting the correct radio buttons.

Edit:  HTML form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsdefault.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/webdefault.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Conference Website">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Conference, website">
    <meta name="author" content="Rafal Dudek">
    <meta name="robots" content="all">
    <title>Conference Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Index</a></li>
            <li><a href="awards.html">Awards</a></li>
            <li><a href="activities.html">Activities</a></li>
            <li><a href="meals.html">Meals</a></li>
            <li><a href="keynote.html">Keynote</a></li>
            <li><a href="workshopschedule.html">Workshop Schedule</a></li>
            <li><a href="registration.html">Registration</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<div id="main">
    <form action="thankyou.html" id="registration" onsubmit="return check()" method="get">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Conference ID</legend>
            <label>Conference ID: <input type="text" oninput="fillForm(this.value)" id="confID" name="confID" size="6" maxlength="6" required="required" pattern="[0-9]{6}" placeholder="123456" title="Enter a 6 digit conference ID number"></label><br />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Personal Information</legend>
            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <select id="title">
                <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
                <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
                <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
            </select><br />
            <label>First Name: <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" size="30" maxlength="100" required="required" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" placeholder="First Name" title="Enter your first name"></label><br />
            <label>Last Name: <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" size="30" maxlength="100" required="required" pattern="[a-zA-Z\-]+" placeholder="Last Name" title="Enter your last name"></label><br />
            <label>Address 1: <input type="text" id="addressone" name="addressone" size="30" maxlength="100" required="required" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\ \#]+" placeholder="Address" title="Enter your address"></label><br />
            <label>Address 2: <input type="text" id="addresstwo" name="addresstwo" size="30" maxlength="100" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\ \#]+" title="Optional:  Enter part 2 of your address"></label><br />
            <label>City: <input type="text" id="city" name="city" size="30" maxlength="100" required="required" pattern="[a-zA-Z\ ]+" placeholder="City" title="Enter your city"></label><br />
            <label title="state">State:</label>
            <select title="state" id="state">
                <option value="AL">AL</option>
                <option value="AK">AK</option>
                <option value="AR">AR</option>
                <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
                <option value="CA">CA</option>
                <option value="CO">CO</option>
                <option value="CT">CT</option>
                <option value="DC">DC</option>
                <option value="DE">DE</option>
                <option value="FL">FL</option>
                <option value="GA">GA</option>
                <option value="HI">HI</option>
                <option value="IA">IA</option>
                <option value="ID">ID</option>
                <option value="IL">IL</option>
                <option value="IN">IN</option>
                <option value="KS">KS</option>
                <option value="KY">KY</option>
                <option value="LA">LA</option>
                <option value="MA">MA</option>
                <option value="MD">MD</option>
                <option value="ME">ME</option>
                <option value="MI">MI</option>
                <option value="MN">MN</option>
                <option value="MO">MO</option>
                <option value="MS">MS</option>
                <option value="MT">MT</option>
                <option value="NC">NC</option>
                <option value="NE">NE</option>
                <option value="NH">NH</option>
                <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
                <option value="NM">NM</option>
                <option value="NV">NV</option>
                <option value="NY">NY</option>
                <option value="ND">ND</option>
                <option value="OH">OH</option>
                <option value="OK">OK</option>
                <option value="OR">OR</option>
                <option value="PA">PA</option>
                <option value="RI">RI</option>
                <option value="SC">SC</option>
                <option value="SD">SD</option>
                <option value="TN">TN</option>
                <option value="TX">TX</option>
                <option value="UT">UT</option>
                <option value="VT">VT</option>
                <option value="VA">VA</option>
                <option value="WA">WA</option>
                <option value="WI">WI</option>
                <option value="WV">WV</option>
                <option value="WY">WY</option>
            </select><br />
            <label>Zip Code: <input type="text" id="zipcode" name="zipcode" size="10" maxlength="10" required="required" pattern="[0-9]{5}\-[0-9]{4}" placeholder="Zip Code" title="Enter zip code"></label><br />
            <label>Telephone: <input type="text" id="tel" name="tel" size="30" maxlength="100" required="required" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" placeholder="Telephone" title="Enter telephone number"></label><br />
            <label>Email: <input type="email" id="email" name="email" size="30" maxlength="100" required="required" pattern="([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Zaz]{2,4})" placeholder="example@example.com" title="Enter email address"></label><br />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Company Information</legend>
            <label>Company Website: <input type="url" id="website" name="website" size="30" maxlength="100" placeholder="www.example.com" title="Enter website URL"></label><br />
            <label>Position: <input type="text" id="position" name="position" size="30" maxlength="100" required="required" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\ \#]+" placeholder="Position" title="Enter your position"></label><br />
            <label>Company Name: <input type="text" id="companyname" name="companyname" size="30" maxlength="100" required="required" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\ \#]+" placeholder="Company Name" title="Enter company name"></label><br />

        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Dining Information</legend>
            <p>
                Would you like a full meal or just day 2 dinner?<br />
                <label><input type="radio" id="mealone" name="meal" value="full" required/> Full Meal ($250)</label>
                <label><input type="radio" id="mealtwo" name="meal" value="part"/> Day 2 dinner only ($75)</label>
            </p>

        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Workshop Information</legend>
            <p>
                Which workshops would you like to join?<br />
                Outdoors Theme:
                <label><input type="radio" id="sesonea" name="session_1" value="workshop_1" required /> Lawn Maintenance</label>
                <label><input type="radio" id="sesoneb" name="session_1" value="workshop_2"/> Landscaping Ideas</label>
                <label><input type="radio" id="sesonec" name="session_1" value="workshop_3" /> Pest Control</label><br />
                Home Improvement Theme:
                <label><input type="radio" id="sestwoa" name="session_2" value="workshop_4" /> Kitchen Remodeling</label>
                <label><input type="radio" id="sestwob" name="session_2" value="workshop_5"/> Bathroom Remodeling</label>
                <label><input type="radio" id="sestwoc" name="session_2" value="workshop_6" /> Home Improvement Ideas</label><br />
                Repair Basics Theme:
                <label><input type="radio" id="sesthreea" name="session_3" value="workshop_7" required/> General Appliance Troubleshooting</label>
                <label><input type="radio" id="sesthreeb" name="session_3" value="workshop_8"/> Heat and A/C Unit Maintenance</label>
                <label><input type="radio" id="sesthreec" name="session_3" value="workshop_9" /> Plumbing Basics</label><br />
            </p>

        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Billing Information:</legend>
            <label>Billing First Name: <input type="text" id="billfirstname" name="billfirstname" size="30" maxlength="100" required="required" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" placeholder="First Name" title="Enter first name"></label><br />
            <label>Billing Last Name: <input type="text" id="billlastname" name="billlastname" size="30" maxlength="100" required="required" pattern="[a-zA-Z\-]+" placeholder="Last Name" title="Enter last name"></label><br />
            <p>
                Card Type:<br />
                <label><input type="radio" id="carda" name="card" value="visa" /> Visa</label>
                <label><input type="radio" id="cardb" name="card" value="mastercard" required/> MasterCard</label>
                <label><input type="radio" id="cardc" name="card" value="americanexpress"/> American Express</label>
            </p>
            <label>Card Number: <input type="text" id="cardnumber" name="cardnumber" size="16" maxlength="16" required="required" pattern="[0-9]{16}" placeholder="0000000000000000" title="Enter credit card number"></label><br />
            <label>Card Security Value: <input type="text" id="csv" name="csv" size=4 maxlength="4" required="required" pattern="[0-9]{4}" placeholder="000" title="Enter CSV number"></label><br />
            <label>Exp. Month (two digits): <input type="text" id="cardexpmonth" name="cardexpmonth" size="2" maxlength="2" required="required" pattern="(0[1-9]|1[0-2])" placeholder="MM" title="Enter two digit month"></label><br />
            <label>Exp. Year (four digits): <input type="text" id="cardexpyear" name="cardexpyear" size="4" maxlength="4" required="required" pattern="[2][0]([1-2][6-9])" placeholder="YYYY" title="Enter four digit year"></label><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

        </fieldset>

    </form>

</div>

<div id="footer">
    <address>
        <small>
            Contact Information:<br>
            Peter John<br>
            12345 Grape St.<br>
            Thornton, CO 80233<br>
            Telephone: 303-555-6666<br>
            E-mail: <a href="mailto:peter.john@gmail.com">peter.john@gmail.com</a>
        </small>
    </address>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Adding get and set cookie functions too just in case:

```html
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

//This function gets cookie value based on conference ID
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, we can't see how this can even work, coz there's no HTML to this? Please provide a [mcve] to clarify us and not drive us like it's driving you! :)

Comment: Sorry,  added HTML form as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are stored as Strings so when you do `if(newArray[1])` you are saying `if("false")` or `if("true")` which in javascript

> The result is false if the argument is the empty String (its length is zero); otherwise the result is true

source: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

and answer that gave source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8693015/1309377

Any of your "false" are treated as `true`

to fix this you should be doing `newArray[1] == "true"`

```js
//This function fills in the form based on entered conference ID

var newArray = ["true", "false", "true"] //newCookie.split(";");

if (newArray[0] == "true") {
  document.getElementById("mealone").checked = true;
} else {
  document.getElementById("mealtwo").checked = true;
}

if (newArray[1] == "true") {
  document.getElementById("sesonea").checked = true;
} else if (newArray[2] == "true") {
  document.getElementById("sesoneb").checked = true;
} else {
  document.getElementById("sesonec").checked = true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsdefault.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/webdefault.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Conference Website">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Conference, website">
  <meta name="author" content="Rafal Dudek">
  <meta name="robots" content="all">
  <title>Conference Registration</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="main">
    <form action="thankyou.html" id="registration" onsubmit="return check()" method="get">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Dining Information</legend>
        <p>
          Would you like a full meal or just day 2 dinner?<br />
          <label><input type="radio" id="mealone" name="meal" value="full" required/> Full Meal ($250)</label>
          <label><input type="radio" id="mealtwo" name="meal" value="part"/> Day 2 dinner only ($75)</label>
        </p>

      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Workshop Information</legend>
        <p>
          Which workshops would you like to join?<br /> Outdoors Theme:
          <label><input type="radio" id="sesonea" name="session_1" value="workshop_1" required /> Lawn Maintenance</label>
          <label><input type="radio" id="sesoneb" name="session_1" value="workshop_2"/> Landscaping Ideas</label>
          <label><input type="radio" id="sesonec" name="session_1" value="workshop_3" /> Pest Control</label>
        </p>
      </fieldset>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Forgot I was matching a string to book value.  That makes sense now :)