# Discord bot JS Can someone explain what happened and how to prevent it?

Tags: bots, discord.js

When code is:

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  const args = msg.content;
  const command = args.toLowerCase()

  if (command === 'frick'){
    msg.reply('Sorry Sir this is a Christian server so no swearing! >:(');
  }
});
```

message is sent normally

and when I added 'shit' to it

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  const args = msg.content;
  const command = args.toLowerCase()

  if (command === 'frick' || 'shit'){
    msg.reply('Sorry Sir this is a Christian server so no swearing! >:(');
  }
});
```

this was a result
 [it just looped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB7gs.png)

and I know I can add a line which ignores bots but I want it to be active for bots as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `if` statement always evaluates to true, because you are essentially checking `if ('shit')`, [which is truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8693015/12251171) because its length is greater than 0.
2. You aren't ignoring bot messages. So you're creating an infinite loop where `bot sends message -> bot receives own message -> bot sends message -> bot receives own message -> ...`.

To fix 1, make sure you write your `if` statements properly:

```
if (command === 'frick' || command === 'shit') {
```

And to fix 2, you can add a simple `if` to the start of your message handler to check if the author is a bot:

```js
if (msg.author.bot) {
  return;
}
```

Comment: Or at least check if it is your own bot saying it

Answer (score 0):

To make it even shorter you could do:

```
if (command === ('frick' || 'shit')) {
```