# Resetting a simple animation in javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, button, css-animations

I am trying to do a simple animation in javascript. I'd like to start the animation when pressing the "Click Me" button, to reset it by pressing it again and to restart it by pressing it a third time.

The code I am pasting stops working after resetting the animation. What am I doing wrong?

I tried to add some logs to track my variables but I really can't understand the problem.

```js
var terminateConditionFullfiled;

function ClickManager() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
  var pos_top = elem.style.top;
  var pos_left = elem.style.left;
  if (pos_top != 0 && pos_left != 0) {
    elem.style.top = 0 + "px";
    elem.style.left = 0 + "px";
    terminateConditionFullfiled = true;
    WritePosition(elem);
    var tt = document.getElementById("tt");
    tt.innerHTML = "terminateConditionFullfiled = " + terminateConditionFullfiled;
  } else {
    terminateConditionFullfiled = false;
    myMove();
    var tt = document.getElementById("tt");
    tt.innerHTML = "terminateConditionFullfiled = " + terminateConditionFullfiled;
  }
}

function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

  function frame() {
    if (terminateConditionFullfiled) {
      return;
    }
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
      Back();
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + "px";
      elem.style.left = pos + "px";
      WritePosition(elem);
    }
  }
}

function Back() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
  var pos = 350;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

  function frame() {
    if (terminateConditionFullfiled) {
      return;
    }
    if (pos == 0) {
      clearInterval(id);
      myMove();
    } else {
      pos--;
      elem.style.top = pos + "px";
      elem.style.left = pos + "px";
      WritePosition(elem)
    }
  }
}

function WritePosition(elem) {
  var log = document.getElementById("log");
  log.innerHTML = elem.style.top + " " + elem.style.left;
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}

#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p><button onclick="ClickManager()">Click Me</button></p>
<p id="log">Log is here </p>
<p id="tt">terminateConditionFullfiled = </p>
<div id="container">
  <div id="animate"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to reset the animation on the second click and when you click again its resumes from the last moved position?

Comment: No, I want to reset the animation on the second click on the position (0,0), then on a third click the animation will restart from (0,0) and start moving bottom right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from your condition `if (pos_top != 0 && pos_left != 0)`. There you should take a look at the content of your variables `pos_top` and `pos_left`.

During the first click, the content is `""` (an empty string), which returns true in your condition. [Find out why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8692982/6691953).

On the second and third click you may have `pos_top == 123px`. Important to see there is `px` added at the end. This causes your condition always to be `true` and hence it works only the first time.

You could replace this condition with a global variable `running` which is set to `true` when the animation runs and `false` when stopped.

Below a small example which prints out the values of `pos_top` before and after being defined through javascript.

```js
let box = document.getElementById("animate")
console.log("The actual position of the box is: " + box.style.top)
console.log("Let's specify the position now through JS")
box.style.top = "20px"
console.log("The actual position of the box is: " + box.style.top)
```

```css
#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="animate"></div>
```

Comment: @user13748410 You're welcome! Feel free to accept the answer as accepted, so people find the correct answer later faster :)

Answer (score -1):

So if i understand you want on the second click reset animation then the object reaching (0,0)?