# you provided undefined when stream was expected angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, stream, undefined

I am trying to create an autocomplete that receive data from an API for each typing, now i have the displayed each time but first i am always having this error for each type .

> You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

even when i subscribe the data into a variables , nothing happens.
this the immage of the error, and you will see the displayed data[image]

this this my app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.results = this.searchText.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      // delay emits
      debounceTime(300),
      switchMap(value => {
        if (value !== '' && value !== undefined) {
           this.lookup(value).subscribe((value: any) => {
             console.log('data sub:', value);
           });
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      })
    );
  } 

lookup(value: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.appService.autoComplete(value.toLowerCase()).pipe(
      map(results => results.hits.hits)
    );
  }
```

and this is my service.ts

```
  public autoComplete(name: string): Observable<Response> {


    const params = new HttpParams()
        .set('name', name);
    return this.httpClient.get<Response>(this.host, { params});
}
```

also this is my html aswell:

```
 <input type="text" matInput   [matAutocomplete]="auto"
                [formControl]="searchText" >
                <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" >
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let item of results | async " [value]="item._source.firstname">
                    {{item._source.firstname}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't subscribe inside the `switchMap` operator. It is meant to switch from one observable to another. So it should essentially return the observable and the subscription must be at the end of the operators chain. In your case, the subscription is done by the `async` pipe in the template.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.results = this.searchText.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(''),
    debounceTime(300),    // delay emits
    switchMap(value => {
      if (value !== '' && value !== undefined) {
        return this.lookup(value);      // <-- return `this.lookup()` here
      } else {
        return of(null);
      }
    })
  );
}
```

---

Additional QoL changes:

1. Use [double-bang operator `!!`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/784929/6513921) to check variable validity. Empty string `''` is [falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8693015/6513921).
2. Use RxJS [`iif`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/iif) to conditionally return an observable.
3. Use RxJS [`NEVER`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/const/NEVER) constant instead of `of(null)`.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.results = this.searchText.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(''),
    debounceTime(300),    // delay emits
    switchMap(value =>
      iif(
        () => !!value,
        this.lookup(value),
        NEVER
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks it works , i was stuck in this error  literally for 3 days