# Why doesn't true return when an empty string is included in the conditional statement?

Tags: javascript

I wrote an if statement using the following data.

```
const data = {
  field: ""
}

const data2 = {
  field: "abc"
}

if (data.field && data.field !== data2.field) {
  console.log('not in')
}
```

I was expecting that if condition to return `true`, but it returns an empty string(`""`) so it is not included in the branch.

As shown below, if it is not an empty string(`""`), true is returned. Why isn't `true` if an empty string(`""`) is included in the conditional statement?

```
const data = {
  field: "ccc"
}

const data2 = {
  field: "abc"
}

if (data.field && data.field !== data2.field) {
  console.log('in')
}
```

Comment: Empty strings are falsy. Non-empty strings are truthy.

Comment: Duplicate [In javascript, is an empty string always false as a boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692982/in-javascript-is-an-empty-string-always-false-as-a-boolean)

Comment: Added `&&` as additional relevant duplicate. While `""`  being falsy is indeed relevant, the way the `&&` works is also important for the outcome. `expr1 && expr2 Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2`, because if you change the order of operants `data.field !== data2.field && data.field` you will get `""` in the first and `"ccc"` in the second case (It doesn't change anything about if the final expression is truthy or falsy but it changes the resulting value).